# how can i save "read " error output in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I write a bash file in which i used `read` command to read data from a file.

If the file wasn't there I want to save the error into a text file. I tried:

```
read myVariable < myFile  2> errorFile.txt
```

it doesn't work, and many other efforts faild such as:

```
myVar=`read myVariable < myFile`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect STDERR first before you tell bash to read from a file that doesn't exist

This will work for you:

```
$ read myVariable 2> errorFile < myFile
```

or

```
$ 2> errorFile.txt read myVariable < myFile
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. can you tell me why I should redirect STDERR first for read?

Comment: Doesn't have to be exactly before `read`, just before you make bash open a file that doesn't exist. See updated answer